# How to adjust the grid size after resizing the frame?

Tags: java, swing, resize, frame, grid-layout

I was wondering the following: I have a MainWindow component (which contains a frame (JFrame)) and several other JPanels. Where one JPanel, let's say gridPanel uses the gridLayout as LayoutManager. Now my problem is that I want to adjust (set the size of rows / set the size of columns) after the window has been resized. Can someone tell me how I can achieve actions that can be triggered after resizing the frame as I am not familiar with the listeners involved.

It should be the done on the most "standard" coding practices. Thank you for your response and answers!

Answer (score 2):

If you want your grid to "fill up" a container, or fill up the JFrame, then key is to use proper layout managers to hold the GridLayout-using container. For instance if you add the GridLayout-using container to another container that uses FlowLayout, then the GridLayout-using container will not change size if its holding container changes size. However if you add the GridLayout-using container to another container that uses BorderLayout and to its BorderLayout.CENTER position, then the GridLayout-using container will resize as the BorderLayout-using parent container resizes.

Example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExpandingGrid extends JPanel {
   private static final int GAP = 5;

   public ExpandingGrid() {

      // create a BorderLayout-using JPanel
      JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      borderLayoutPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("BorderLayout Panel"));
      borderLayoutPanel.add(createGridPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER); // add a Grid to it

      // create a FlowLayout-using JPanel
      JPanel flowLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      flowLayoutPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("FlowLayout Panel"));
      flowLayoutPanel.add(createGridPanel()); // add a grid to it

      // set up the main JPanel 
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP, 0)); // grid with 1 row
      // and add the borderlayout and flowlayout using JPanels to it
      add(borderLayoutPanel);
      add(flowLayoutPanel);
   }

   // create a JPanel that holds a bunch of JLabels in a GridLayout
   private JPanel createGridPanel() {
      int rows = 5;
      int cols = 5;
      JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            // create the JLabel that simply shows the row and column number
            JLabel label = new JLabel(String.format("[%d, %d]", i, j),
                     SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // give the JLabel a border
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            gridPanel.add(label); // add to the GridLayout using JPanel
         }
      }
      return gridPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ExpandingGrid");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ExpandingGrid());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Also, if this is not helpful, then you may wish to elaborate more on your problem and post code, preferably an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: I understand that part, however I want the following: I want to have a simple add command that would position my buttons in a grid. However when my frame get's bigger, I want more columns as otherwise the space between the components will increase. That's why I wanted to only adjust the columns. I haven't found any other suitable layoutmanager for this purpose, maybe you could suggest one? (simplicity of the layout manager is needed as I do not want to have an overkill (like using grid bag layout) or something; however if grid bag layout is sufficient (without too much hassle I will try).

Comment: @Anonymous: I suggest that you create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) like the one I created above to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: @Anonymous: My solution is for a fixed number of columns and rows (which is what I thought your original post requested). Also, tell us what you are wanting to do with this GUI, why you want to have these properties as perhaps there's a better way to solve this than what you're trying, such as by use of a JTable.

Answer (score 0):

> That's why I wanted to only adjust the columns.

Maybe the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=wrap%20layout) is what you are looking for.